# Is css_parser parsing inline CSS incorrectly?

Tags: css, ruby, parsing

I have a HTML file with inline CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Page 1</TITLE>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<DIV style="position:relative;width:612;height:792;">
<STYLE type="text/css">
.ft0{font-size:108px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
.ft1{font-size:16px;font-family:Times;color:#000000; }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#A0A0A0" vlink="blue" link="blue">
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:457;left:225"><nobr><span class="ft0">Sample</span>   </nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:62;left:241"><nobr><span class="ft1"><b>HTML</b></span></nobr></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am trying to parse the inline CSS using Ruby's css_parser library. Note that the inline CSS has 2 classes `.ft0` and `.ft1`.

My code is:

```
require 'css_parser'
parser = CssParser::Parser.new
parser.load_file!('filename.html')
puts parser.to_s
```

Which outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>   \n<TITLE>Page 1</TITLE>\n<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<DIV style=\"position:relative;width:612;height:792;\">\n<STYLE type=\"text/css\">\n.ft0 {\nfont-size: 108px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000;\n}\n.ft1 {\nfont-size: 16px; font-family: Times; color: #000000;\n}\n"
```

when I do:

```
parser.find_by_selector(".ft0")
```

it returns an empty array.

It appears as though `css_parser` is seeing the entire string

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Page 1</TITLE>\n<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<DIV style=\"position:relative;width:612;height:792;\">\n<STYLE type=\"text/css\">\n.ft0`

as the selector instead of just the class `.ft0`

Is there a way that I can fix this, so that it just finds the class `.ft0`?

Comment: It looks like you’re telling it to load an HTML file. Doesn’t it just take CSS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CssParser doesn't find the target in HTML, it only wants a style-sheet definition. You need to parse the CSS from the HTML then pass it to CssParser.

This might get you started:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'css_parser'

html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Page 1</TITLE>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<DIV style="position:relative;width:612;height:792;">
<STYLE type="text/css">
.ft0{font-size:108px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
.ft1{font-size:16px;font-family:Times;color:#000000; }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#A0A0A0" vlink="blue" link="blue">
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:457;left:225"><nobr><span class="ft0">Sample</span>   </nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:62;left:241"><nobr><span class="ft1"><b>HTML</b></span></nobr></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

stylesheet = doc.at('style').content
parser = CssParser::Parser.new
parser.add_block!(stylesheet)
puts parser.find_by_selector(".ft0")
```

Which outputs:

```
font-size: 108px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000;
```